# Improving performance of an OUTER APPLY with XML in SQLS

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I'm generating reports from a database that makes extensive use of XML to store time-series data. Annoyingly, most of these entries hold only a single value, complicating everything for no benefit. Looking here on SO, I found a couple of examples using OUTER APPLY to decode these fields into a single value.

One of these queries is timing out on the production machine, so I'm looking for ways to improve its performance. The query contains a dozen lines similar to:

```
SELECT...
 PR.D.value('@A', 'NVARCHAR(16)') AS RP,
...
FROM Profiles LP...
 OUTER APPLY LP.VariableRP.nodes('/X/E') RP(D) 
...
```

When I look in the Execution Plan, each of these OUTER APPLYs has a *huge* operator cost, although I'm not sure that really means anything. In any event, these operators make up 99% of the query time.

Does anyone have any advice on how to improve these sorts of queries? I suspect there's a way to do this without OUTER APPLY, but my google-fu is failing.

Comment: Are you saying that you want a query that assumes there is only one matching node?

Comment: I *think* so, but I'm working on a a sample database with a small selection of properties so I'm not sure I should draw that as a final conclusion. I'm getting the feeling the proper solution would be to simply return the text and parse it using the DOM in VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking this literally

> most of these entries hold only a single value

...it should be faster to avoid `APPLY` (which produces quite an overhead on creating a derived table) and read the one and only value directly:

```
SELECT LP.VariableRP.value('(/X/E/@A)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(16)') AS RP
FROM Profiles LP
```

If this does not provide what you need, please show us some examples of your XML, but I doubt this will get much faster.

- There are XML indexes, but in most cases they don't help and [can make things even worse](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/130969/70663)
- You might use some kind of trigger or *run-once* logic to shift the needed values into a side column (into a related side table) and query from there.

Comment: is that [1] special? Should that not be [0]?

Comment: Performance is MUCH improved! Like 10 times or more. I believe this solves the problem.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Glad to help you! The `[1]` is just *the first* (there is no `[0]` in `XPath`)

Comment: Oh no, I'm having VBA flashbacks!